# AWS Lambda How to read the query parameters

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am trying to read the query parameters passsed from a frontend application in my lambda function. Below is the code of frontend application

```
method: 'GET',
          url: API_ENDPOINT + '/detect',
          params: {
            Image: this.imageKey
          }
```

Below is my lambda code to read the query variable

```
   var params = {
      Image: {
        S3Object: {
          Bucket: process.env.UploadBucket,
          Name: event.Image
        }
      },
    };
```

Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try change your lamda to read the query string like below

```
var params = {
  Image: {
    S3Object: {
      Bucket: process.env.UploadBucket,
      Name: event['queryStringParameters'].Image
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Thats was a quick one @rx100. That worked perfect